React Material Table v1 filtering
I am using v1 version of Material React Table. I need to implement filtering for dates, like "before current date" or "after current date".
Is it possible to do this with default filter and pass it inside custom Filter for header, or i need to implement this filtering by myself?
Cause enableColumnFilterModes isnt working for custom component
currently i have this
and i need something like this
